# How does du determine which hard link to disregard?

Tags: linux, filesystems, du

We have two directories:

```
$ ls -l
total 8
drwxr-x--- 2 nimmy nimmy 4096 Nov 15 19:42 jeter
drwxr-x--- 2 nimmy nimmy 4096 Nov 15 19:42 mariano
```

I create one file in the first folder:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=jeter/zero_file.1 bs=512000 count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512000 bytes (512 kB) copied, 0.268523 s, 1.9 MB/s
```

This is the output of `du`:

```
$ du -sh *
504K    jeter
4.0K    mariano
```

As expected, if I place a hard link of the `zero_file.` in the other folder `du` output does not change:

```
$ ln jeter/zero_file.1 mariano/zero_file.2
$ du -sh *
504K    jeter
4.0K    mariano
```

However, as far as I'm aware, there is nothing in the filesystem that points to `zero_file.1` as the original file. So how does `du` know to count `zero_file.1` but not `zero_file.2`?

It cannot be a timestamp comparison because all hard links share one inode; they'll have the same timestamp data correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Extending your test to three folders, you can see that only the first time the inode is hit does `du` count it. If you go into the individual folder and run `du`, you'll get the full size.

To test:

```
mkdir alexandru
ln mariano/zero_file.2 alexandru/zero_file.0
du -sh *
```

You should now see `alexandru` taking up the 500K+. So without looking at the `du` code, I'm guessing it stores a list of traversed inodes and doesn't revisit the ones already seen.

Comment: I see. So it traverses the directories alphabetically and keeps track of seen inodes. At least that's what further testing on my side conclude.

Comment: I believe that du only traverses directories alphabetically in the cases above because that is the way that the glob expands the wildcard *.  I could be wrong about this, but I don't recommend counting on the order being alphabetical.

Comment: @Slartibartfast you are correct, running `ls | sort -r | xargs du -hs` shows the last folder as being 500 K. So it does track inodes in the order it sees them, whether that's alphabetical or otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

If you do

```
du -sh jeter jeter mariano
```

Then you get 2 different sizes for jeter.

This seems to be in keeping with the finding above...

... except shouldn't the 1st value be the total and the 2nd value be zero?

Comment: Although weird, that's consistent with Dennis Williamson's first POSIX quote, which states that the inode is only remembered for "files with multiple links", implying that files that have only a single (hard) link will be counted every time the directory is included, while those with multiple links will only be counted the first time. +1 for finding an interesting edge case.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, when `fstat(3)` sees that the number of hard links is greater than one, it records the inode number for subsequent matching. According to [POSIX](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/du.html):

> Files with multiple links shall be counted and written for only one entry. The directory entry that is selected in the report is unspecified.

The shell expands the `*` glob in lexical order, according to [POSIX](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_03):

> If the pattern matches any existing filenames or pathnames, the pattern shall be replaced with those filenames and pathnames, sorted according to the collating sequence in effect in the current locale.

However, when `du -sh` is done without globbing, the order has to be decided in some way, but it sounds like it must be implementation dependent.

Note that these two commands give different results:

```
du -sh jeter mariano
du -sh mariano jeter
```

Comment: When `du -sh` is done without globbing, the user (caller) will have decided on the order that they provided the arguments. (e.g., `jeter mariano` or `mariano jeter`) When it's done *with* globbing the order is still not decided by `du` itself, it's decided by the shell, as per your second quoted POSIX passage.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check whether or not your backup from rsync time machine work, and possibly more important how much backup space you are saving, you should do a `ls -cr | xargs du -hs` which will feed the directories to `du` in the correct sequence (reversed time of creation).

Comment: This is not an answer to _this_ question. And `ls -c` sorts by _inode change time_, not _create time_ (which is generally not stored).